# Query MongoDB Using 'ObjectId'

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have inserted `document`s into MongoDB without an `id`. And I want to retrieve them by searching through their [MongoDB `ObjectId`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/), that has been assigned *in default*.

Here is my attempt-

```
var query_id = Query.EQ("_id", "50ed4e7d5baffd13a44d0153");
var entity = dbCollection.FindOne(query_id);
return entity.ToString();
```

And I get following error-

> A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred

What is the problem?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You need to create an instance of `ObjectId` and then query using that instance, otherwise your query compares `ObjectId`s to string and fails to find matching documents.

This should work:

```
var query_id = Query.EQ("_id", ObjectId.Parse("50ed4e7d5baffd13a44d0153"));
var entity = dbCollection.FindOne(query_id);
return entity.ToString();
```

Comment: This answer is nearly correct. At least in C#, it appears that there is no longer a FindOne() method. Replace it with FindOneAs() instead. Here's a link to a good example,  this one uses FindAs(), but it's the same principle: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12345580/2705003

Comment: There is now no longer a FineAs or FindOneAs method, Minhas Kamal answer should be referenced instead

Comment: As soul-check mentions. The _id field is NOT a string, but a more complex datatype called ObjectId.

Answer (score 38):

In **C#** for latest official **MongoDB.Driver** write this-

```
var filter_id = Builders<MODEL_NAME>.Filter.Eq("id", ObjectId.Parse("50ed4e7d5baffd13a44d0153"));
var entity = dbCollection.Find(filter).FirstOrDefault();
return entity.ToString();
```

We can accomplish the same result without converting `id` from string to `ObjectId`. But then, we will have to add `[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]` before `id` attribute in the model class.

The code can even be further simplified using **lambda expression**-

```
var entity = dbCollection.Find(document => document.id == "50ed4e7d5baffd13a44d0153").FirstOrDefault();
return entity.ToString();
```

Comment: Upon `ObjectId.Parse(cool_id.ToString())` I continually get that the guid is "not a valid 24 digit hex string" - what an I doing wrong?

Comment: @VincentBuscarello, as it says, your cool_id has not valid string representation. Might be use of ObjectId.TryParse(cool_id.ToString(), out ObjectId parsedResult) instead?

Comment: @minhas-kamal can you help me on my query above soln not works in my case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74835380/how-to-do-a-partial-search-of-mongdb-object-id-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 4):

If you're here in 2018 and want copy/paste code that still works or pure string syntax;

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task QueryUsingObjectId()
    {
        var filter = Builders<CosmosParkingFactory>.Filter.Eq("_id", new ObjectId("5b57516fd16cb04bfc35fcc6"));
        var entity = stocksCollection.Find(filter);
        var stock = await entity.SingleOrDefaultAsync();
        Assert.NotNull(stock);

        var idString = "5b57516fd16cb04bfc35fcc6";
        var stringFilter = "{ _id: ObjectId('" + idString + "') }";
        var entityStringFiltered = stocksCollection.Find(stringFilter);
        var stockStringFiltered = await entityStringFiltered.SingleOrDefaultAsync();
        Assert.NotNull(stockStringFiltered);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The selected answer is correct.  For anyone confused by the Query.EQ, here is another way to write a basic update (updates the entire mongodb document):

```
string mongoDocumentID = "123455666767778";
var query = new QueryDocument("_id", ObjectId.Parse(mongoDocumentID)); 
var update = new UpdateDocument { { "$set", documentToSave } };
mongoCollection.Update(query, update, UpdateFlags.Multi);
```

The ObjectId object is needed when you want to actually search by object ID, otherwise it is comparing string to objectid type, and it won't match.  Mongo is very type-strict in this way, regardless if the field name is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it this way, its

```
public static ObjectId GetInternalId(string id)
    {
        if (!ObjectId.TryParse(id, out ObjectId internalId))
            internalId = ObjectId.Empty;

        return internalId;
    }
```

then in your method you can do something like this

```
ObjectId internalId = GetMongoId.GetInternalId(id);
        return await YourContext.YourTable.Find(c => c.InternalId == internalId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Note: id param in GetInternalId its a parameter on that method. In case you need as this:

```
public async Task<YourTable> Find(string id)
    {
        ObjectId internalId = GetMongoId.GetInternalId(id);
        return await YourContext.YourTable.Find(c => c.InternalId == internalId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }
```

Hope it helps also.

Answer (score 0):

With the MongoDB.Driver 2.23.1 and dotnet 6.0

```cs
// Example schema
public class NoteTags
{
    [GraphQLIgnore]
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Mongo db query with `_id`

```cs
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;

class SampleQueryByID {
  public GetTags() {
    var client = new MongoClient( /** Mongo Settings */ );
    var db = client.GetDatabase("db");
    var tagsCollection = db.GetCollection < NoteTags > ("tags");

    var findOptions = new FindOptions {
      BatchSize = 10
    };
    FilterDefinition < NoteTags > filter; = Builders < NoteTags > .Filter.In(
      "_id",
      TagsIds.Select(tag => ObjectId.Parse(tag)) // Very important to parse
    );

    // res variable to hold the mongo db query result
    var res = new List < NoteTags > ();

    // use the above filter and filter option
    using(var cursor = tagsCollection.Find(filter, findOptions).ToCursor()) {
      if (cursor.MoveNext()) {
        var d = cursor.Current.ToList();

        for (int i = 0; i < d.Count; i++) {
          res.Add(d[i]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```