# MongoDB and Guid in Linq Where clause

Tags: linq, mongodb

I store an object in mongodb which contains a Guid. Mongodb converts the Guid to a binary value

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("52cf4a467b302a4797db23e8"),
  "name" : "test",
  "guid" : new BinData(3, "qZ8PQdmDv0+K500wnj6skA=="),
}
```

I get an empty result set when I use the Guid in a Linq expression and the count is always 0.

```
var queryable = _database.GetCollection<MyObject>("myname").AsQueryable();
var guid = new Guid("410f9fa9-83d9-4fbf-8ae7-4d309e3eac90");
var count = queryable.Where(x => x.Guid == guid).Count();
```

The reason is that Linq generates the following request

```
count: "member_variables", query: { panelid: "410f9fa9-83d9-4fbf-8ae7-4d309e3eac90" }
```

but the request should be

```
count: "member_variables", query: { panelid: new BinData(3, "qZ8PQdmDv0+K500wnj6skA==") }
```

I tried various Linq expressions, but none worked.

```
queryable.Where(x => x.Guid.ToString() == guid.ToString())
```

throws the exception: "Unable to determine the serialization information for the expression: x.Guid.ToString()."

```
queryable.Where(x => x.Guid == new BsonBinaryData(guid));
```

throws the exception: "Unsupported where clause: ((BsonBinaryData)x.Guid == UuidLegacy:0x24f7ceb84f06d143b6426e8f01cb7825)."

How can I request the documents?

Note: I need to use IQuerable and can't use Mongodb queries.

Comment: Check out this related post...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14315684/query-mongodb-using-objectid

Comment: I found a solution:
    queryable.Where(x => Query.EQ("guid", guid).Inject())