# MongoDB C# driver: Using Linq to get Guid returns nothing

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb, guid

The following is the code I am using to query the database. The variable "filter" is a linq expression. It seems that I can use this code to get data using ObjectId or any other value that may be in the document. But when I store a Guid and try to retrieve it, there is no return. Is there something I am doing wrong here, or is there a limitation on MongoDB itself when it comes to Guids?

```
        _dbSet = mongoDatabase.GetCollection(collectionName);
        var query = _dbSet.AsQueryable<TEntity>();

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        return query.ToList();
```

**EDIT:**

Just to clarify a bit more. I have tried the solution shown here in the last comment: [MongoDB and Guid in Linq Where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21051096/mongodb-and-guid-in-linq-where-clause). That does not give me a result either. The data I am trying to retrieve contains just the _id field.

```
{
    "_id" : LUUID("e5bdda3b-ae6a-d942-bd43-c8c7a6803096")
}
```

The entity being used to retrieve this object has only a property called Id which, from what I understand, translates to the _id field in the Mongo document. So I tried retrieving on the Id property as well. Still no result.

Comment: What is `filter`, does the same filter give you the desired results say, in the MongoDB console?

Comment: filter is Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>

I see that Mongo is storing the Guid as some sort of binary data. I am not really concerned about querying in the shell just using the c# driver.

Comment: The question about running it in the shell was more geared towards, "Does your query actually deliver the results you think it should deliver" before you try and figure out why it's not delivering the results in C#. That may or may not be possible test, depending on if your filter maps to a standard query.

Comment: Ah, ok. Well, from what I can tell, the query in the shell would look different than what the query would look like in the code. Especially since I am using Linq to do the querying. Not to mention, I would need to do some sort of conversion of the Guid I am trying to find before I pass it into the Find in the shell. I am specifically trying to use Linq and do the following to get a document.

`entity=>entity.Id == Guid`

Comment: Well, I haven't done any C# Mongo things, but I know with Node.js wrappers the ID is returned as an ObjectID (at least it was when I used it) so searching for ID required me to wrap an GUID string essentially `new ObjectID(myGuidString)` to perform the query on it. Again, this may not apply in C# but it's a thought.

Comment: That would not work at all as ObjectIds are 96 bit and Guids are 128 bit. There would be loss of data going from Guid to ObjectId. That means that any pulls of the data from the database would have Ids that are not correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was an error in my part. It looks like the Guid that was being returned back was not in the correct format in the viewer I was using. Robomongo likes to default to something they call a LegacyUUID however this is not the same format as the .Net Guid. I needed to change the options in the viewer make it display the correct Guid for me to look for.

Comment: what did you change?

Comment: @SunnySharma I'm a bit late in answering. I apologize. It's been quite a while since I've used Robomongo. From what I recall, it was just a change of format for the UUID in the UI. Judging from your answer below, it looks like you've found it. Hopefully this helps some other who fall into the same trap of different UUID formats.

Answer (score 4):

Extending @jjkim's answer as I could not post image in comment:

You need to change the preference which comes under "**Edit > Preferences**" in **Studio 3T for MongoDB**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That was very helpful