# How to find mongoDB object by ObjectID w/MongoDB Shell?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-shell

How can I do this in the MongoDB shell?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14315888/8887398

Basically I'm trying to find objects by their ObjectId. All are failing so I assume it's trying to compare to string. I'm doing this directly in the MongoDB shell. Here's what I've tried:

`db.myTestDB.find( {_id: 3254ummx213u5k815mn2v2 })` 
Result: SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal

`db.myTestDB.find( {_id: "3254ummx213u5k815mn2v2" }`) 
Result: Nothing

`db.myTestDB.find( { "_id": "3254ummx213u5k815mn2v2" })`
Result: Nothing

`db.myTestDB.find( {_id: ObjectId("3254ummx213u5k815mn2v2") })`
Result: Nothing

I just put a random ID in there for my examples, but I've verified the ID exists, and by looking on MongoDB Compass.

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/#objectid), you construct an `ObjectId` by using the `new` keyword. For example:

```
db.myTestDB.find( {_id: new ObjectId("3254ummx213u5k815mn2v2") })
```

So, you were on the right track with the last attempt in your question, you were only missing the `new` keyword.

Here's a more complete example. Given the following docs:

```
db.getCollection('X').find({})

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59d0ada3c26584cd8b79fc51"),
    "name" : "A"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59d0adafc26584cd8b79fc54"),
    "name" : "B"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59d0b2b4c26584cd8b79fd7c"),
    "name" : "C"
}
```

This shell command will load one of those docs, by id:

```
db.getCollection('X').find({_id: new ObjectId("59d0ada3c26584cd8b79fc51")})

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59d0ada3c26584cd8b79fc51"),
    "name" : "A"
}
```